# Avertissements sur le contenu d'une question

Tags: discussion

Récemment, j'ai cherché la signification d'expressions anglaises pour lesquelles on demandait une traduction en français. En utilisant un moteur de recherche en ligne, ce que j'ai découvert m'a un peu dégoûté. Comme la question était très simple, sans autres détails que l'expression à traduire (un modèle similaire à : « Comment dit-on *“Ma petite vache a mal aux pattes”* en français ? »), la recherche de signification de ma part s'est entièrement déroulé hors du site.

On pourrait donc dire que je suis entièrement responsable de ce que j'ai trouvé, et que l'opinion que j'en ai ne concerne que moi. On m'a éventuellement reproché d'avoir utilisé des expressions comme *Ça semble dégueux* ou *Un sentiment de répulsion pourrait survenir chez certains usagers*. Je crois que la personne m'ayant critiqué était tout bien intentionnée, et d'ailleurs, elle m'a renvoyé au Code de conduite de Stack Exchange, duquel elle a extirpé :

> No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language. Even if you don’t intend it, this can have a negative impact on others.

Pour le moment, mes commentaires dans cette brève discussion mènent au jeu des pouces, mais ça ne représente possiblement rien dire d'autre que l'approbation de certains quant à mon commentaire sur le fait que l'OP eût pu être un peu plus explicite sur la nature possiblement choquante de la question, pas forcément l'approbation de termes dévalorisants dans mon premier commentaire sur la question.

- Y a-t-il un processus en place pour permettre d'identifier des questions qui pourraient ne pas convenir à tous ?
- En général, si notre question n'est possiblement pas digeste pour tous, est-on encouragé à expliciter ce fait d'une manière ou d'une autre ? Ou à ne pas poser la question du tout ?
- Existe-t-il des tags *rouges*, ou quelque autre outil de ce genre qui puisse indiquer que les gens pourraient ne pas être très excités par ce qu'ils trouveraient dans une question, avant de s'y rendre ?
- Si je me sens choqué ou dégoûté par le contenu d'une question, et que je sens n'avoir pas eu suffisamment de signes pour me préparer à cette éventualité, quel comportement devrais-je adopter ? Minimiser l'expression de ce sentiment ? Conserver mes griefs pour moi-même ? Utiliser des tournures euphémisées ?

Comment: éventuellement (possibly) ≠ eventually (finalement)

Answer (score 2):

J'ai retrouvé [la question concernée](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/42266/comment-dit-on-en-fran%C3%A7ais-biscuits-and-gravy-et-cookies-and-milk) et toute cette situation semble se baser sur une incompréhension entre toi et ton interlocuteur dans les commentaires. Je me trouve être celui qui a édité ton premier commentaire, qui indiquait :

> ***That sounds awful**. Can you give details on what exactly you're referring to, as this could lead to an impressive (and possibly undesirable) array of answers.*

J'ai interprété "*that sounds awful*" comme étant dirigé vers le message de l'auteur, et non la nourriture auquel il/elle faisait référence. Dans cette interprétation, il s'agissait d'un commentaire offensant et peu accueillant puisqu'il apportait un jugement non-constructif.

Il se trouve que l'auteur de la question a également peu apprécié la formule et a répondu à l'instant :

> *I was offended and decided to drop out from Stackexchange because it felt a little attacking.*

Et même si ce n'était pas le cas, cette phrase n'apportait rien à la question, il s'agissait d'un jugement, si léger soit-il, qui devait être supprimé. **Le reste du message était pertinent** et ouvrait la voie pour améliorer la question, il méritait donc de rester.

Pour répondre aux questions posées :

- **Non**, il n'existe pas (à ma connaissance) de procédure pour identifier une question qui pourrait ne pas convenir à tous. Si une telle question est posée, la plupart du temps, elle enfreindra de toute façon les règles du site. Et si ce n'est pas le cas, c'est notre rôle en tant que modérateurs d'arbitrer ce genre de situation (par exemple en ajoutant un [18+] devant une question qui porterait sur du vocabulaire sexuellement explicite).
- Je pense qu'il faut en effet encourager les gens à mettre un *disclaimer* devant une question qui pourrait choquer. Il me semble avoir lu quelques exemples sur d'autres sites du réseau lorsque certains sujets sensibles étaient abordés (harcèlement, etc.). Comment faire cela sans risquer d'offenser l'auteur ? Cf ma réponse au point 4.
- **Non**, il n'existe (à ma connaissance) aucun outil de ce genre. Je trouve que l'idée est intéressante, et comme elle pourrait concerner tout le réseau, n'hésite pas à la suggérer sur [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).
- Si quelqu'un se sent choqué par une question, la bonne attitude à adopter est de laisser un commentaire **constructif** expliquant quel est le problème et proposer comment améliorer la question afin que de futurs lecteurs ne soient pas choqués (**encore mieux : proposer un édit à la question de base**). Par exemple, dans le cas présent :

> *When I did my research on the terms you mentioned in your question, some of the results were a bit shocking to look at. I recommend that you add a disclaimer in the beginning so that people are warned.*

Pour rappel, **être agréable ne coûte rien et permet au site de rester accueillant**. Maintenant, je crois qu'il est temps de faire un peu de nettoyage dans les commentaires de cette question.

Comment: En recherchant les nourritures en question, je suis bel et bien tombé sur des pratiques sexuelles pour le moins particulières. Ça m'a laissé un peu froid. J'ai peut-être conclus un peu rapidement. Merci pour la réponse et une possibilité pour mentionner le problème sans attaquer.

Comment: Puisque mes agissements ont fait fuir quelqu'un, il semble que je sois ici un troll. Peut-être devrais-je suspendre mes activités. Aux côtés du troll délibéré, il y a aussi le troll involontaire. Les dommages individuels ne sont pas forcément moindre pour le second, même s'ils seront généralement moins nombreux.

Comment: Ça n'a pas été mon cas donc je pensais que tu avais été uniquement dégoûté par la nourriture en elle-même. Quoi qu'il en soit, le fond de mon message est qu'il est important pour des utilisateurs plus anciens de donner un bon exemple en étant accueillants dans la façon de suggérer des améliorations.

Comment: Faire une erreur de forme ne fait pas de toi un troll, et l'auteur de la question est revenu sur le site et a finalement trouvé une réponse satisfaisante. Tout est bien qui finit bien. :)

Comment: @Reyedy *That sounds awful* n'était clairement pas une attaque vers l'OP mais un commentaire sur la chose en question et ce qu'elle pouvait inspirer. J'ai du mal à comprendre comment ça a pu être perçu autrement. Je trouve aussi dommage que mon commentaire qui montrait que *biscuit and gravy* n'inspirait rien, ou du moins rien qui soit agréable à des Anglais, commentaire où je faisais un clin d’œil pour montrer qu'il n'était pas agressif, ait été supprimé. L'OP a d'ailleurs repris la même expression que celle que j'avais utilisée (*(American-style) biscuits are not a thing*).

Comment: Ton commentaire a été supprimé car l'auteur l'a "flaggé" comme offensant, donc j'ai préféré supprimer tout ce qui pouvait offenser l'auteur du post, par sécurité, pour ne garder que les commentaires qui apportaient quelque chose sur le fond.

Comment: J'admets pleinement mon erreur. J'ai d'emblée perçu les 2 objets de la question comme étant des expressions, et les ai cherchées telles quelles, avec guillemets, sur Google. La présomption (que c'était des expressions toutes faites) m'est venu si naturellement que j'en ai oublié que je l'avait établie comme axiome, alors que tout un chacun n'avait pas forcément à le faire de son côté. Reyedy semble me pardonner ce manquement. J'ai personnellement plus de difficulté à me pardonner. Je connais le sentiment de se faire rabrouer en ligne, et j'ai encore honte d'avoir causé ce trouble à l'OP.